# Footable how to append row to top?

Tags: javascript, html, footable

Hi I am using footable and am using the appendRow function.

```
footable.appendRow(data);
```

How can have the row added to the beginning instead of end?

Here is the script

```
https://pastebin.com/VmJG2Wde
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by sorting the table each time a new row is appended

```
$('.footable').data('footable-sort').doSort(0, false);
```